# Change Hostnames and IP Addresses with another host - Does it require a DNS update?

Tags: server, administration, infrastructure

I have a new Linux database server I am working on with a certain hostname and ipaddress. I want to change it's hostname and ipaddress with my old Linux database server's at the time of going live with the new server. I understand this requires only update on the new server's hosts file.

My team says it would need a DNS update. I don't see why it would require a DNS update. Because a DNS is a mapping between hostname and ipaddress and it hasn't changed.

Could anyone clarify?

Thank You, Madhuri Dara

Answer (score 0):

normally, yes indeed, a DNS is a mapping between IP addresses and hostname.
However, I would also recommend to delete the old one an re-create them to perform a re-discovery of the routes.
The best option for you would be here to have a DNS manager into your domain, this way, you could modify them here, instead of into your DNS file in each machine.